# Automatically generating walls for android brickbreak game

Tags: android, andengine

I have a game plan which run on Android and generated helps of Andengine and Box2d and in this plan we are trying to make a simple brick break game.

In this game we need so many diffirent walls like rectangle, circle, polygon which comprise of diffirent walls or bricks .

How can i create wall contructer class which is in Andengine?

I would like to use this class for generate diffirent types of walls ie;circular, polygonal or rectangular.....

Is there a simple way?

I'm going to attack an example of walls

http://www.google.com.tr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FKB%2Fdirectx%2FSuperBrickBreaker%2FSuperBrickBreaker.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F5832%2FSuper-Brick-Breaker-A-Simple-DirectDraw-Game&h=361&w=500&tbnid=giYlGzdeotkzuM%3A&zoom=1&docid=8zGuLsx0jBoccM&ei=tx2PVO3TDqXhywOE04HYCQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygDMAM&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1132&page=1&start=0&ndsp=25

Answer (score 0):

I would extends the `Rectangle` class, or the `Sprite`/`TiledSprite` class , and use polymorphism.
Each brick would be one of your class which extends the ones i mentioned before.